# HLS (m3u8) playback issues with JWPlayer. Crashes flash. Cloud files issue?

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, jwplayer, cloudfiles

http://embed.asset.tv/hls/index.1.html

I've been trying to get HLS streaming on JWplayer working for quite a while now.

I know JWPlayer supports it. (We have a premium account)

We've used the wizard builder and the embed code we use works with their example video file.

However when we create our own m3u8 version of our videos, they wont play back.

We use Zencoder and their recommended method of m3u8 creation. 
https://app.zencoder.com/docs/guides/encoding-settings/http-live-streaming

We use rackspace cloud files as our CDN.

At this stage I don't know if the issue is with m3u8 or the Cloud files CDN having an issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need a crossdomain.xml file here - http://codezoo.co.uk/crossdomain.xml

Reference - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28844/crossdomain-file-loading